# Make One column in Microsoft List editable for all employees all other will be read only

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, microsoft-lists

I have created a Asset Management List in Microsoft List with multiple columns.

I want the users to give only edit access to one column while all other will be in read only mode.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to set the column level permissions using SharePoint out of the box functionalities. SharePoint only supports unique permissions until "item" level in the lists.

**Workaround**:

1. [Customize the SharePoint list form using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
2. Set `DisplayMode` property of data cards or required controls to:

   ```
   DisplayMode.Disabled
   ```
3. You can also do it conditionally like below to keep fields editable for owner of the list:

   ```
   If(User().Email = "abc@company.com", DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayMode.Disabled)
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   If(User().Email = "abc@company.com", Parent.DisplayMode, DisplayMode.Disabled)
   ```

**References**:

1. [How to make an auto populated field read only](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-make-an-auto-populated-field-read-only/td-p/187355)
2. [How to Mark Power Apps Form Fields as Read Only](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-Mark-Power-Apps-Form-Fields-as-Read-Only/td-p/1471226)